# Problem with login / reset password links in users emails

Tags: password, reset

I have a problem with passwords for users. User want to reset his password. He is getting email with link. But, when he clicks on it, it opens in browser with additional sign on the end:
https://www.mywebsite.sth/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=RGf6btVYiq0htL2UM9Y5&login=usr_login%3E.
The additional string is "%3E", which is an ascii for ">" 
I have no plugin for login, it's just standard wordpress link.
Where should I start to look for a cause of the problem?

Comment: Are you using any plugin to change email template ?

Comment: no, I had TME, and I thought that it is a cause of problems, but I've deactivated it and nothing changed :( I don't use any email custom templates.

Comment: in my pluggable.php I found this line: $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n"; and it seems to be ok. Where else can I look for this extra string?

Comment: What theme do you use? Also can you message me the website link? I'll be able to check as you don't sure about this.